# Flutter doctor is not running

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

When I run the flutter doctor command it keeps loading infinitely

I'm installing Flutter on my computer, I've already set the environment variables, I've already installed Android Studio and nothing works.

Comment: How long have you waited? First time might take some time since it also downloads some resources.

Comment: I've already configured Flutter several times, so I knew it could take a while, but I've left it for over an hour and it hasn't started yet.

Comment: SOLVED the solution was to remove it from the D folder and extract it elsewhere in my case it was in documents to test and it worked